# How to disable Flashing when tapping PresentationLink (SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

How can I disable the highlighted color when a button is tapped?

Now when I tap it, it gets gray and the action gets called, but I want to disable it.
Is it possible at the moment?

```
PresentationLink(destination: NextView()) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some code.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`PresentationView` does not seem to have a way of styling the button, and I doubt it'll ever will. However, there are other methods to present a view. Below you have an example that will avoid the effect. It is a little more verbose, but it will serve your purpose.

***As of beta3, modals seem to have a bug, and the onDismiss method is never called. So it is hard to reset the isPresented variable properly. In the meantime, I use a workaround for that. Check this answer for that:*** https://stackoverflow.com/a/56939555/7786555

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            // Option #1, with blink
            PresentationLink(destination: NextView(), label: {
                Text("Click to show")
            })

            // Option #2, without blink
            Text("Click to show").color(.blue).tapAction { self.isPresented = true }
                .presentation(isPresented ? Modal(NextView()) : nil)
        }

    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("aloha!")
    }
}
```