# Navigation Button Can't Dismiss Modal

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI has unexpected behaviors with `.sheet` that I haven't been able to work out. Here is a simple Master > Detail View that uses the same modal. One in a `NavigationView` the other in `.navigationBarItems`:

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var modal: some View {
        ModalView(showModal: $showModal)
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Can be dismissed") { self.showModal = true }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.modal }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) { Text("Can't be dismissed") }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var modal: some View {
        ModalView(showModal: $showModal)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Dismisss?") { self.showModal = true }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.modal })
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal View")
            Button("Dismiss") { self.showModal = false }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that, though `ModalView` can be dismissed from the `Button` in `MasterView` it cannot be dismissed with the `.navigationBarItems` in `DetailView`

Anyone know how to dismiss a `.sheet` invoked from `.navigationBarItems`?

EDIT: Interestingly if you switch

```
 Text("Detail View")
```

with

```
Button("Can Dismiss") { self.showModal = true }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.modal }
```

You get very unexpected results, causing the `.navigationBarItems` to be disabled unless the modal was dismissed via a drag gesture

EDIT 2: This behavior has now been filed as a bug with id: FB6891155

Answer (score 2):

This definitely warrants a bug report. Initially I thought that using `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` might solve this issue but it does absolutely nothing to change the behavior.

What I did find is that you can get the modal to be dismissible if you only have 1 `sheet`. I.e. if you delete the `sheet` call from your `DetailView`.

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var modal: some View {
        ModalView()
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Can be dismissed") { self.showModal = true }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) { self.modal }
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(showModal: $showModal)) { Text("Can't be dismissed") }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Dismisss?") { self.showModal = true })
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var showModal

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Modal View")
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.showModal.value.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this does make the modal programmatically dismissible, you do end up encountering the second bug that you referred to, which is that the `.navigationBarItems` is disabled until you go back [SwiftUI button in navigation bar only works once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162633/swiftui-button-in-navigation-bar-only-works-once)

[image: video of code in action]