# SwiftUI Sheets: Inconsistent sheet behaviour with navigationBarItems

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Xcode: Version 11.3 (11C29)
Target: Simulator running iOS 13.3

I'm getting inconsistent behaviour that's hard to diagnose when working with sheets and SwiftUI. When I:
 * Use a button in the `NavigationView` itself, I can consistently call up the sheet and dismiss it
 * Use a button in the bar of the `NavigationView` (i.e. `navigationBarItems`), the behaviour is inconsistent: sometimes it toggles without issue, sometimes it will "lock up" and not respond for ~10 seconds before functioning again. Swiping around and performing other actions in the interface seem to help in "resetting" the functionality.

Minimum reproducible example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isModalShowing = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(1..<5) { number in
                        Text(String(number))
                    }
                }
                Button("First Modal Button") {
                    self.isModalShowing = true
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button("Second Modal Button") {
                    self.isModalShowing = true
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isModalShowing) {
            TestView(isPresented: self.$isModalShowing)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello SwiftUI!")
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.isPresented = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

To note:
* Pressing `First modal button` works consistently
* Pressing `Second modal button` works inconsistently after dismissing the modal for the first time (try using this button ~5-10 times in a row, it should lock up, but it's hard to predict when it will)

There's already [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278944/xcode-11-beta-5-modal-triggers-only-once) StackOverflow questions/[answers about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170669/sheet-shows-only-once-and-then-never-again), but none have worked for me so far and they seem to talk about the Xcode Betas, whereas I am on stable (hopefully 11.3 is stable). Different ways of passing the state (`@Binding` vs `@Environment`) didn't help. Moving around where the `.sheet` is called also didn't change anything. I think it's also related to the `List` and/or `ForEach` but I'm new to Swift and not sure how to debug further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. Though my answer isn't going to solve this problem, but can give you options to consider.

Out of curiosity, I did some debugging of the view hierarchy. With the current setup, initially the navigation bar button stays here (highlighted as blueish color):

[image]

Then you present the sheet and do the dismissal of the sheet accordingly. After the dismissal, the position of the navigation bar button isn't quite right. See:

[image]

The `Text` of the button stays in the right position, but the bar button is displaced from where it should be.

**But this displacement doesn't happen if you use `NavigationLink` instead of `.sheet` presentation.**

Well, this issue is prevalent for the `large` option of `TitleDisplayMode` of navigation bar title, and it's the default for a quite long. But if the `inline` option is used, the issue doesn't exist. See, with the `inline` option, before and after the sheet dismissal the navigation bar button stays at the same place:

[image]

---

So that means, you now have two options to consider:

1. Use `NavigationLink` instead of sheet presentation. You can do this by placing the below code inside the outermost `View` (in your case the `VStack`):

   ```
   NavigationLink(destination: TestView(), isActive: self.$isModalShowing) {
       EmptyView()
       // no need to provide any other view as it will be triggered by the action
       // of navigation bar button item which already provides its own view
   }
   ```

> Note: This `NavigationLink` option isn't tested with **Xcode 11.3** or newer as navigation link seems to misbehave with this version. But works as expected upto **Xcode 11.2.1**. More on [SwiftUI unable to navigate back and forth with navigationLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483962/swiftui-unable-to-navigate-back-and-forth-with-navigationlink)

2. Use the `inline` option of the navigation bar `TitleDisplayMode` as:

   ```
   .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"), displayMode: .inline)
   // you can get rid of the title "Home" with empty "" string though
   ```

Comment: Great and detailed answer! I ended up implementing the second option as it's just a toy project and I don't particularly care about the looks. Works consistently! Last question: should I be reporting this bug somewhere?

Comment: Yes! You can. There are [discussion forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome), [feedback assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) for this purpose. But I never bothered.

Comment: Thanks @nayem this was driving me insane!

Comment: Thanks @nayem now I can avoid these hidden view hacks

Answer (score 0):

A different way to dismiss the modal sheet:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello SwiftUI!")
            Button("Dismiss") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP: `Different ways of passing the state (@Binding vs @Environment) didn't help.` Or did you modify something else as well that I missed?

Comment: The code above has no state passing. Instead it uses the built-in `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`. Try it and see, just don't wrap your `TestView` with an `.environment()` modifier -- the code uses a built-in environment var.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me, but this one does -- dropping down to UIKit for a different `dismiss` function:  [What is different between @Binding and scroll down to dismiss presented view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937835/what-is-different-between-binding-and-scroll-down-to-dismiss-presented-view)

Answer (score 0):

There is a **workaround** by using a Text view with onTapGesture, however you'll lose the Button color animation when tapped.

[image: workaround]

The code would be something like:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
    Text("Text")
        .onTapGesture {
            self.isPresentingSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresentingSheet, content: {
            SheetView()
        })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way in dealing with this problem while still using a button and a large title. Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isModalShowing = false
    @State var opacity: Double = 1

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {

            List() {

                // Some views here

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"), displayMode: .automatic)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: 

                Button(action: {

                    self.opacity = 0.5
                    self.isModalShowing = true

                }, label: {

                    Image(systemName: "plus")

                })

                    .opacity(self.opacity)
                    .scaleEffect(1.5)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isModalShowing,
                           onDismiss: {
                               self.opacity = 1
                        },    
                           content: {

                               NewView(onDismiss: self.$isModalShowing)

                        })
                )
           }

      }
}
```

Basically, we change the opacity when the button is tapped, and change it back when the sheet is dismiss which I think would force the button to update itself.

As for dismissing the sheet, OP's way works in this case